# Keras loss weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've model with two output layers, age and gender prediction layers. I want to assign different  weight values for each output layer's loss. I've the following line of code to do so.

```
model.compile(loss=[losses.mean_squared_error,losses.categorical_crossentropy], optimizer='sgd',loss_weights=[1,10])
```

My question is what is the effect of loss weights on performance of a model? How can I configure the loss weights so that the model can perform better on age prediction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the book [Deep Learning with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python) by François Chollet:

> The mean squared error (MSE) loss used for the age-regression task
>   typically takes a value around 3–5, whereas the crossentropy loss used
>   for the gender-classification task can be as low as 0.1. In such a
>   situation, to balance the contribution of the different losses, you
>   can assign a weight of 10 to the crossentropy loss and a weight of
>   0.25 to the MSE loss.

Comment: The book from the author of Keras https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python