# Working with multiple losses and their weights in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

Training a GAN model using train_on_batch with multiple losses, can I use random `loss_weights` while compiling a model or is there some specific strategy to use these loss weights as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620057/keras-loss-weights?answertab=oldest#tab-top). In my problem, `mean_sqaured_error` is a loss function for generated_image and original_image and `binary_crossentropy` is a classification loss function for 0 and 1 class.

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=['mean_squared_error', 'binary_crossentropy'], loss_weights=[100,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The weights are hyper parameters that you need to optimize. Notice that optimizing these hyper parameters is not simple, due to the fact that lowering the weights will automatically decrease the loss (which we usually aim to minimize), but will not necessarily create a better model. MSE can range between [0, infinity) if not normalized, or, e.g. [0, 1] if the features are normalized between [0,1] (and a sigmoid is used). Binary cross entropy values can range between [0, infinity), which make sthe process not as simple as we may think. Without any knowledge of your specific problem I will try first using the default weights (1 each).