# How to predict two numerical columns using keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression, prediction

I am new to machine learning . I am trying to predict two numerical columns from a data set. The columns that i have to predict are Amount and number of days .
Amount, number of days are features and all other columns are labels.

```
ID  Category    Company Amount  No_of_days
x1  c1             A    338.07   5
x2  c2             B    46.21    35
x4  c1             C    1480     35
x1  c3             C    2018     48
x2  others         A    4344    -10
```

I have tried fitting the data set with neural network from keras 
Pre processing steps I have done are one hot encoding and min max scalar.

I have tried adding more layers,more neurons,changing number of epochs,and activation layer to sigmoid and leaky relu.

Code:

```py
model = Sequential()

# The Input Layer :
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='normal',input_dim = X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))

# The Hidden Layers :
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))

# The Output Layer :
model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear'))

# Compile the network :
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

checkpoint_name = 'Weights-{epoch:03d}--{val_loss:.5f}.hdf5' 
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True, mode ='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32,validation_split = 0.2, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Keras Functional API Code

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
visible = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
X = Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu')(visible)
X = Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu')(X)
X = Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu')(X)
out1 = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear')(X)
out2 = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear')(X)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=[out1, out2])
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
model.fit(X_train,[y_train[:,0], y_train[:,1]] ,epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

The Predicted two columns are no way match with actual test columns and RMSE Score that am getting is 40860.So i don't know how to move forward to get more accurate prediction.Kindly help me where i am going wrong? where i have to make the changes to predict multiple columns?

Comment: Can you give more details, what is the training accuracy you are getting and val accuracy as well?

Comment: loss: 0.0078 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0078 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0094  @RAMSHANKERG

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to output such varying values from one layer. Instead, make a layer for each, and attach a loss function to each. Check out this page: 
https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models
You'll need the functional API.

Edit: I would try using loss weights. Your model is confused because
the loss values are so vastly different. Each output is on a different
scale entirely.

While this answer uses different loss functions, the idea is the same:

[Keras loss weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620057/keras-loss-weights)

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss={
        'out1': 'mean_absolute_error', 
        'out2': 'mean_absolute_error'
    },
    loss_weights={'out1': 1., 'out2': 0.2}
)
```

Comment: I followed your link and i tried to make prediction with two layers with keras functional api but I could see some Improvement in RMSE Score but still accuracy is poor.I have updated my functional api code in the question @DasHund

Comment: Updated my response.

Comment: Thanks for the update @DasHund but when i tried to compile with your update iam getting this error.
ValueError: Unknown entry in loss dictionary: "out1". Only expected the following keys: ['dense_9', 'dense_10']

Comment: add name='out1' and name='out2' to the respective constructor:

out1 = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear', name='out1')(X)
out2 = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear', name='out2')(X)

Also, based on that message, you probably need to reset your runtime if you are in a notebook.

Comment: Thanks @DasHund Its Working but still I am not getting the accuracy.I measured the RMSE score for two columns separately first columns(no_of_days) am getting 14 and the second column amount am getting 62455.
Since second columns is related to currency am i missing something in preprocessing or somewhere else?
Both the feature columns has negative values will there be a problem with the negative values?

Comment: It's hard to tell without some domain knowledge of the data. Negative values are generally fine, so long as your inputs are mostly homogeneous. Since you are using a min max scaler, you are likely fine. You may want to try and take some of the customization off. Let the initializer use the default, etc. Is this a public data set you can link me to? There are a few test you can run to validate your pipeline, and see if your data. Check out this article https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607

Comment: ok @DasHund I will try with default initializer and sorry the data is not public. But the sample data i have given is very similar to original data.I am using the same 5 columns and 10,000 rows for training but the dataset that i have to apply this algorithm is huge.